# Verifying that ArcInfo Workstation is Installed?

Tags: c#, vba, vb, arcinfo-workstation

What is the best way to verify that a machine has ArcInfo Workstation installed? A code sample in VBA, VB or C# would be great!

Comment: Set up a remote system event viewer looking for Fortran errors? ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have access to poke around in the registry (happens to me often) a poor-mans method would be to look for the system environment variable ARCHOME. If that's there, check under that for the existence of the executable file ARCHOME\bin\arc.exe (or, on Unix, $ARCHOME\bin\arc.exe).

Because the default "Program Files" folder contains spaces, you are more likely to find ARCHOME at somewhere like : "C:\arcgis\arcexe10x".

ARCHOME is required to be set for ArcInfo Workstation to operate correctly, and it will be removed from the environment on uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

They say it's acceptable to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), so here goes.

Workstation should install a key in Windows's registry. So just search the registry to see if it exists.

Here is an example in VB.NET:

```
Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey 
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ESRI\\ArcInfo\\Workstation\\8.0") 
If key Is Nothing Then 
  'Workstation is not installed'.
End If
```

Comment: Does it remove that key on uninstall?

Comment: Good question Jason.  I'm not sure.

Comment: the registry key may not be in the same location on 64bit systems (even for 32bit programs).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBS fragment I used for uninstalling Google Earth via a startup script.  You can use these WMI objects to poll machines for the ArcInfo Workstation installation, assuming it's registered in the product catalogue.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = 'Google Earth'")
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
 objSoftware.Uninstall()
Next
```

Reference:

[Documentation for the Win32_Product class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28VS.85%29.aspx).
[WMI Made Easy for C#](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/)